# C# DateTime Format YYMMDDhhmmsstnnp

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm currently using a third party DLL to run some of my programs.

It was working fine until recently I decided to move it to a new server running OS Windows Server 2016.

The library suddenly pops an error saying:

System.FormatException: Incorrect format. 'YYMMDDhhmmsstnnp'

I looked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings but couldn't see anything for t, nn and p.

Does anyone recognize the format above and knows what actually is t nn and p?

And how do I actually resolve the issue?

Thank you

Comment: I don't recognise YY or DD, either. `t` is valid and represents (at least on my culture) a single-character am/pm indicator.

Comment: This isn't much to go on. You may have to use ILSpy or Reflector to reverse engineer the DLL and figure out a little more. Or you could try checking for differences in server configuration, especially the globalization settings, to see if anything obvious comes up.

Comment: Check the Servers DateTime Settings. The System DateFormat is what is being popped as Error. Other way that I can think of is to Set the Thread Culture when you Application Starts. Set the Date Format to something that you expect. With nothing Set, .NET defaults to the OS formats.

Comment: it may sound odd that I am asking about DB. but does this app access DB, and if so are to trying to use new sql server DB?

Comment: @JohnWu - Agree with you - My assumption is that - OP says library was okay until he moved to Server 2016. Hence, I adviced to confirm if external factors are okay.

Comment: Chor Wai Chun - Is this a licensed dll or a nuget? Can you share details? May be open the dll in ildasm and look at the Exception throwing method/functionality if you can spot YYMMDDhhmmsstnnp formatting used - as JohnWu is suspecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after a little detective work (well, a search) I believe you're probably using the `SMPPClient` library, and that the error comes from [this line](https://github.com/ArdanStudios/SMPPClient/blob/6bbb616cfdaa4801024a528e8672ed31c03cc326/SMPP/SmppClient/SubmitMultiSm.cs#L65). It's not trying to use that as a format string - it's only reporting it (unhelpfully, IMO) as the expected format of the string.

It's actually *checking* it using this regex:

```
"^[0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-9][0-4][0-9][\\+\\-R]$"
```

The [SMPP v5 specification](http://opensmpp.org/specs/smppv50.pdf) explains the formatting:

> - ‘YY’ last two digits of the year (00-99)
> - ‘MM’ month (01-12)
> - ‘DD’ day (01-31)
> - ‘hh’ hour (00-23)
> - ‘mm’ minute (00-59)
> - ‘ss’ second (00-59)
> - ‘t’ tenths of second (0-9)
> - ‘nn’ Time difference in quarter hours between local time (as expressed in the first 13 octets) and UTC (Universal Time Constant) time (00-48).
> - ‘p’:
>   “+” Local time is in quarter hours advanced in
>   relation to UTC time.
>   “-” Local time is in quarter hours retarded in
>   relation to UTC time.
>   “R” Local time is relative to the current SMSC time.

This isn't something I'd expect a regular format string in .NET to handle.

I would suggest that your next steps should be:

- Find out what value it was trying to parse (that could be tricky, I understand)
- Work out where that value comes from (is it generated elsewhere in the code, possibly in your code, or is it data originating outside your system?)
- Write a small program to *just* perform that regex on both the working machine and the problematic machine to work out whether the problem is that the regex behaviour has changed, or the data being parsed has changed

My *guess* is that some code somewhere is using regular `DateTime` formatting to create part of this string, and then tweaking it for the last part... and that on your new system, there are some locale changes that affect things. For example, even if you format with an explicit format, that will still use the *calendar system* of whatever culture it's using - if you're formatting to a non-Gregorian calendar accidentally, that could definitely affect things. (The common fix there is to explicitly use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when formatting a machine-readable string.)

Comment: you're right, this is the thing I'm working on, although not the same library, mine was third party licensed, but I guess they are using the same regex though, let me see if I can dig up the codes he used and see what's the value he use.

Comment: @ChorWaiChun: Not just the same regex, but the same *exact* error message. I wonder whether they're both from some common codebase... Fortunately that doesn't change what your next steps would be :)